# implementing bfs on negative numbered nodes

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

We can easily implement breadth first search algorithm if the nodes or vertices are numbered positive in C++.

But how to deal with it when the nodes or vertices are numbered negative.

Suppose a node is numbered -200 and if we assign `bool visited[-200] = true or false` then it would produce run time error.

What will be the approach in this case?

Answer (score 0):

*"if nodes are numbered negative"* ~> in case you need each node to have a unique identifier that will be used to access these nodes within some containers, there's no reason why you would allow the value of such identifier to be negative.

Just like you pointed out: `visited[-200] = true;` makes no sense. In case you need each node to have a unique `id` / `index` of this kind, do it regardless the value stored within it, i.e.:

```
struct Node {
    unsigned int id;
    int value;
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with graph labels it seems a reasonable approach is the use of *property maps* (see, e.g., the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/using_property_maps.html). The basic idea is to access the node properties via a structured approach where the details of the properties are actually access are subject to the concrete property map being used.

Based on what you are saying you are accessing the labels using a node ID. There are two obvious approaches with somewhat different characteristics depending on the actual layout of the IDs:

1. If the node labels are relatively dense and the range of value node IDs is known, using an array with a suitable adjustment using an offset is a reasonable approach. That is, you'd use an array like `label[nodeID - minNodeID]`.
2. If the node labels are randomly distributed, you'd use an associative container with the node ID as the container's key.

If you can control the layout of your node representation, you should probably consider storing the labels in the node, especially if the node IDs are randomly distributed.

Comment: which associative container are u suggesting here?

Comment: @RahulKumarSingh: Something like `std::set<int>` or `std::unordered_set<int>` would do (you'd use the flag returned from `insert()` to determine if the node was labeled already) although I would try hard to either use an array or embed the labels into the node.

Comment: kuhl can u provide me with the code that checks if the node is labeled already?

Comment: @RahulKumarSingh: `if (!labels.insert(id).second) { /* id was already in the set, i.e., the node is already labeled */ }` For more information see the STL documentation.